# Compare two dates in R

Tags: r, date, equality

I have a tab-separated text file that I imported to R. I used the following command for the import:

```
data = read.table(soubor, header = TRUE, sep = "\t", dec = ".", colClasses =c("numeric","numeric","character","Date","numeric","numeric"))
```

When I run `str(data)` to check the data-types of my columns I get:

```
'data.frame':   211931 obs. of  6 variables:
$ DataValue   : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 NA ...
$ SiteID      : num  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
$ VariableCode: chr  "Sucho" "Sucho" "Sucho" "Sucho" ...
$ DateTimeUTC : Date, format: "2012-07-01" "2012-07-02" "2012-07-03" "2012-07-04" ...
$ Latitude    : num  50.8 50.8 50.8 50.8 50.8 ...
$ Longitude   : num  15.6 15.6 15.6 15.6 15.6 ...
```

A reproducible sample of the first 20 rows of my data is here:

```
my_sample <- data.frame(
  DataValue = rep(c(0, NA, 0), c(9L, 8L, 3L)),
  SiteID = rep(1, 20L),
  VariableCode = rep("Sucho", 20L),
  DateTimeUTC = as.Date(c(
    "2012-07-01", "2012-07-02", "2012-07-03", "2012-07-04", "2012-07-05",
    "2012-07-06", "2012-07-07", "2012-07-08", "2012-07-09", "2012-07-10",
    "2012-07-11", "2012-07-12", "2012-07-13", "2012-07-14", "2012-07-15",
    "2012-07-16", "2012-07-17", "2012-07-18", "2012-07-19", "2012-07-20"
  )),
  Latitude = rep(50.77, 20L),
  Longitude = rep(15.55, 20L)
)
```

Now I want to filter my table by the date. Note that I'm running my code inside a `for` loop. First, I subset my data by 1st July 2012 and do some processing. Then, I subset my data by 2nd July and do some processing, and so on.. For example, I want to get all rows with date equal to 6th July 2012. I tried the code:

```
startDate = as.Date("2012-07-01");
endDate = as.Date("2012-07-20");
all_dates = seq(startDate, endDate, 1);

#the following code I'm trying to run inside a loop...
for (j in 1:length(all_dates)) {
    filterdate = all_dates[j];
    my_subset = my_sample[my_sample$DateTimeUTC == filterdate,]
    #now I want do do some processing on my_subset...
}
```

But the above code returns an empty dataset starting from step 7 of the loop.

So, for example:

```
subset_one = my_sample[my_sample$DateTimeUTC == all_dates[6],]
```

returns: `3 obs of 6 variables`.

But, for some unknown reason, the example:

```
subset_two = my_sample[my_sample$DateTimeUTC == all_dates[7],]
```

returns: `0 obs of 6 variables`.

(note: I edited the above code to make my problem 100% reproducible)

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: `data[data$DateTimeUTC == as.Date("2012-07-04"),]` Please read an introduction to R to learn basic subsetting.

Comment: @Roland: Your example works and returns the desired results, but for some reason when I set the filter date programatically (such as inside a for loop), I get an empty dataset. I edited my example code to clarify my problem.

Comment: I can't help you without a reproducible example. However, I'd bet my lunch that you don't need a `for` loop and shouldn't use one.

Comment: I edited the example even more to make it reproducible. It's very strange. Without the `for` loop, the subset is correct. Within the `for` loop, the subset is always empty.

Comment: An example is not reproducible without some data that exhibits the problem. Use `dput(head(data))` to provide a small data sample that we can paste in an R session.

Comment: @Jake Burkhead: you are correct, with the first 10 or 20 rows the code works. But when my dataset is really huge (200,000 rows) the subsetting by Date stops working. So it's really difficult for me to reproduce the problem. Maybe I'll try to extract a sample from the middle or end of my dataset...

Comment: Look up "split apply combine" to see how you can get rid of the `for` loop.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The following solution solved my problem:
Instead of using the `Date` data type, I tried to use the `POSIXct` data type.
Here is the example code for reading the tab-separated textfile after which the subsetting worked in all steps of my `for` loop:

```
data = read.table("data.txt", header = TRUE, sep = "\t", dec = ".", 
    colClasses =c("numeric","numeric","character","POSIXct","numeric","numeric"));
startDate = as.POSIXct("2012-07-01");
endDate = as.POSIXct("2012-07-20");
all_dates = seq(startDate, endDate, 86400); #86400 is num of seconds in a day

#the following code I'm trying to run inside a loop...
for (j in 1:length(all_dates)) {
    filterdate = all_dates[j];
    my_subset = data[data$DateTimeUTC == filterdate,]
    #now I want do do some processing on my_subset...
}
```

Comment: I used similar approach. I replaced loop with `subset` command so I used subset(data, data$DateTimeUTC %in% all_dates). In my case I need to wrap data with `as.Date` function - subset(data, as.Date(data$DateTimeUTC) %in% as.Date(all_dates))